# PHP mail() timeout

Tags: php, email

First a few infos:

- Debian Squeeze
- PHP 5.3.3
- PHP with mod_cgi
- I absolutely HAVE to use `mail()` in this case. For all my other projects I already use SMTP mailing.

I have isolated the problem of a site timeout to the PHP `mail()` function. This is the only line of code in a test.php file on my server:

```
<?php mail('rudolf@geardev.de', 'test', 'test');
```

Which seems to take endless and is then terminated by mod_cgi after 40 seconds. The command

```
php -r "mail('rudolf@geardev.de', 'test', 'test');"
```

on the command line sends the email instantly.

Please tell me which log files you want to see, the Apache log is this:

```
[Thu Jan 17 12:17:00 2013] [warn] [client 178.15.148.43] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 40 seconds
[Thu Jan 17 12:17:00 2013] [error] [client 178.15.148.43] Premature end of script headers: test.php
```

I think the problem is that I accidentally ran `chmod -R 775` on the root directory a few days ago. I fixed all errors already, besides this one.

Comment: run `phpinfo()` and see if you have the sendmail extension activated.

Comment: Inspect your `/var/log/mail.log` for errors

Comment: Is this happening only when you're using mail function?

Comment: Stop using the mail function. You have a low chance of emails sent by it to land in Inbox. Best use a SMTP class (there are dozens out there) to send via a local SMTP account. That will ensure this problem goes away and you email has a grater delivery chance. Make sure you set To and From headers.

Comment: mod_cgi also a not so good choice. Try suphp or mod_php.

Comment: Sendmail is activated. I will, sorry! The mail.log is empty. I know that, but not using mail() is not an option, there are a few scripts on the server that I didn't develop.

Comment: PHP can be configured to use an SMTP server instead of sendmail.

Comment: But wouldn't conflict that with the "From" headers? The SMTP probably accepts only one email address as from, the one from the owner.

Comment: Does the apache user on the server have permissions to send mail? This could explain why running `php -r` as the root user works but php scripts (run as user apache, usually) don't send. You may want to chmod /usr/sbin/sendmail, or whatever setup you use to send mail.

Comment: As sayed before, it's look a permission issue. Are you running suhosin, apparmor or any other tools to hardenize your webserver? By the way, try execute `<?php system('php -r "mail('rudolf@geardev.de', 'test', 'test');"'); ?>` - if works forgot all I sayed.

Comment: It is definitely a permission issue! The question is, what permissions are wrong?! Btw, the ``system()`` script also time out. I use suhosin, but I didn't reconfigure it and it was working before, too.

Comment: This has helped me on many Debian servers:

http://serverfault.com/questions/173762/php-mail-function-painfully-slow-on-local-development-machine

Comment: @Bolli That's not the problem. It doesn't just take long, it takes *forever*. It ran for an hour already, no success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely you use 2 different php.ini versions. one for cli and one for cgi. Debian have this setup i believe.

- /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini
- /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

Make sure that your cli and cgi versions have the same email configuration and it will work.

The mail configuration key is:
[mail function]

Another possibility is that your web user does't have access to **execute** sendmail.

Also check spool permissions (updated)

Comment: The sendmail paths are absolutely identical, I triple checked that.

Comment: What permissions do I have to check to make sure sendmail is allowed to be executed? The /usr/sbin/sendmail binary has permissions 777 (Also checked 755).

Comment: Put this in your sendmail.cf
DontBlameSendmail=GroupWritableDirPathSafe
restart and try again.

Also, when you are sending the email form php.. didi you checked the mail log?  if you did, whats the error being displayed? Probably apache dont have right to send mails because its not in the smtp group or something like that.
Not being on smtp would remove access from spool directory since u ran a chmod 775...

Comment: It was the /var/spool/postfix directory that needed rights 777! Thank you very very much! I just started a new bounty and gave it to you.

Comment: I will give it to you tomorrow, I have to wait 24h first.

Answer (score 2):

Do not rely on `mail()` as it is unreliable and leads to issues just like these. I've used [phpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) for years quite happily.

If you persist on `mail()` then check your settings in php.ini (explained at http://www.quackit.com/php/tutorial/php_mail_configuration.cfm). Note that usually CLI has a different php.ini than FastCGI.

Some more common problems:

- FastCGI doesn't have permissions to use sendmail
- Memory limit with large attachments

Comment: As I said already, I absolutely HAVE to use it in this case. For all my other projects I already use SMTP mailing. I don't send any attachment. Mails worked perfectly before my chmod, it shouldn't be the configuration, but I check it.

Comment: The configuration of sendmail is correct, plus it works on the command line with the same settings.

Comment: If it works from the command line, it could be FastCGI or configuration - as on unix boxes you usually have different php.ini for CLI and web. Also check the permissions for FastCGI, does it have access to sendmail?

Comment: I checked the sendmail path with a ``phpinfo()``, it is correct. The permissions are the same as on another server of mine that is working perfectly.

Comment: There are more options to check than just path. Execute sendmail from php via system() and see what that prints to stderr or returns. But still, different php.ini files and permissions are the ones worth investigating.

Comment: What permissions do I have to check to make sure sendmail is allowed to be executed? The /usr/sbin/sendmail binary has permissions 777 (Also checked 755).

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for this particular error and have found that it can be caused by a variety of things. I do not know what you have already tried to do to fix it, but here are some suggestions as to what might help:

- Make sure to start with `<?php` and end with `?>`
- Make sure to chmod the file to 755
- Try to include an output of some sort (eg. print "Mail sent.")

There's also another question about this subject here on SO: [PHP Mail Function Causes Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725575/phps-mail-function-causes-a-500-internal-server-error-only-after-a-certain-po) - The owner stated that a change of server with the same setup resulted in a working mail() function, which could indicate a problem with the host.

Comment: I can't just change the server because it is a root server with dozens of sites and about ~1TB data.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have a firewall blocking outgoing SMTP connections?  Are there other things on that server that can successfully send email?

*I would make this a comment, but am not allowed to yet.*

Comment: See above, I can even send it through PHP if I use the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a problem using:

```
exec('php -r \"mail('rudolf@geardev.de', 'test', 'test');\"');
```

Comment: `system`, `exec` all are same. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378175/php-mail-timeout#comment20107655_14378175) comment