# PHP Mail freeze

Tags: php, email, timeout

Each time I sent a mail with php the site freezes for 120 seconds before spitting out an Fatal Error timeout exceeded. I tried to isolate the issue by creating a site with only this code:

```
 $to = 'my mail here';
            $subject        = 'invite';
            $from           = 'from our mail';
            $message        = 'asdf';

            if(mail($to, $subject, $message))
            {
                    echo 'sent to ' . $to;
            } else {
                    echo 'error';
            }
```

But this does not work either. The mail gets sent SOMETIMES which really buggs me. How can I debugg this? Am using Apache on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug by making php to show the error logs. You can use below code by placing it at top of your php code as:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(-1);
?>
```

Another thing i noticed in your email sending code is that it does not contain headers. Headers are necessary for an email functionality to work properly.

```
<?php
$to = "testing@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "This is a test email message.";
$from = "testing1@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
    echo "Mail is Sent.";
}else{
    echo "Mail not sent.";
}
?>
```

Comment: I've tried that. Only Fatal error time exceeded are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP on Windows you have to provide a SMTP server in `php.ini` file. Check in your configuration if you have [SMTP configuration directive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp) configured properly. Timeout might occur because PHP can't reach proper server.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [PHP mail() timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378175/php-mail-timeout). I suspect you have a similar problem.

Also, confirm that the settings you're using in your php.ini are what's recommended by your internet service provider (if you are doing this through localhost), or your hosting provider (if you are using a hosting service for your server). Some providers require wonky settings for outgoing emails.